# How to implement Search location functionality in osm map android application

Tags: android, maps, osmdroid

I am able to call GPS location(My current location) inside osm map. but now i want to implement search direction and search location in my application.i just want to know the way how to implement these functionalities.

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is not very clear...

"Search direction": if you want a routing feature => look at [OSMBonusPack](http://code.google.com/p/osmbonuspack/wiki/Overview) routes and directions.

"Search location": if you want to be able to search a place by its name => look at [OSMBonusPack](http://code.google.com/p/osmbonuspack/wiki/Overview) Geocoding and Reverse Geocoding.